# The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a rather complex code have been on for two days, I am using the map operator from rxjs operator to bring the values of `IUser` from the `IUser` interface. But I keep getting this error:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<IUser, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'IUser': email, displayName, token.

Thanks in advance.

Account.service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { IUser } from '../shared/models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(null!);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(values: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', values).pipe(
      map((user: IUser) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(user)
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

login.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

User.ts

```js
export interface IUser  {
    email: string;
    displayName: string;
    token: string;
}
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the observable? Anyways, `map` will always return something (nothing meaningfull in your code). I suspect that you should use `tap` instead or potentially have the function return nothing and do that logic inside `subscribe` directly inside `login`.

Answer (score 1):

From [`HttpClient` `post()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post),

> **Overload #14**

```js
post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        context?: HttpContext;
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<Object>;
```

Without specify `T` for `.post()` [Overload #14], it will return `Observable<Object>` value.

> **Overload #15**

```js
post<T>(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        context?: HttpContext;
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<T>;
```

From `post()` [Overload #15], you have to specify `T` for example `post<T>()`, so that it will return `Observable<T>` value.

---

### Solution

**Assumption**:  The response returned is `IUser` type.

1. Specify `T` as `IUser` or `any` type to solve the error mentioned.
2. As @Gunnar's comment, you have to use **[`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap)** instead of [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to perform the operation from the source observable **without altering it**.

   Using **`map` must return a value for `Observable`**.

```js
login(values: any) {
  return this.http.post<IUser>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', values).pipe(
    tap((user: IUser) => {
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        this.currentUserSource.next(user);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: When I used "tap", it still returns the same error Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'IUser': email, displayName, token.

Comment: Hi, may I know the error is came from which part?

Comment: Have been on this for days and haven't still gotten the error away. I still need your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to create minimal, reproducible example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)? It is hard to debug and solve the issue without you specify more details on the issue faced.

Comment: The error is still from "Account.service.ts" when I tried using tap instead of map.

Comment: Ohk I'll do that on StackBlitz and post the link here

Comment: Ok noted with thanks and good luck, meanwhile you can also share the screenshot for the code part hit error and the error message to the comment as well.